# Center View (CheckBox) which uses layout_weight in TableRow column

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which I am inflating in order to dynamically add [TableRows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) into a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). I use layout_weight to stretch the columns to the desired width.

The table is put inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) so I can scroll between the generated rows. I also have a table header that I put in a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) on top. I did this because I don't want to scroll the header. That is also why I don't use layout_span instead of layout_weight.

The problem is that one of the Views in the TableRow is a [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) and I want it centered, but since the layout_width attribute is '0' I can not use layout_gravity="center" to center it.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/order_form_line_TableRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_product_description_TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_present_CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_facings_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_free_cu_given_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_order_quantity_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_free_order_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_wholesaler_Spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_delivery_date_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</TableRow>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: CheckBox not centered]

This is how I want it to look:
[image]

*The colors are for representational purpose only. They can be ignored.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help. Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this :

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/order_table_row_present_CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. You set me on the right track. I ended up using a RelativeLayout with layout_width="0dp" since having a 0-based width was necessary and RelativeLayout is more light-weight than LinearLayout. It doesn't seem to have a noticeable impact on performance. Thanks again

Comment: This seems to work, but why is encapsulating the checkbox in another layout the only working solution? Seems more like a hack than a proper way to do it.